# Whole word search with multiple matches and non-word characters

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to match all instances of a whole word, along with leetspeak alternatives, in a string. For example, let's take this string:

```
brΦwn 8rown The quiçκ brΦwη fox βrown b®øwΠ brownie
```

I'm trying to capture the 5 "brown" instances, but not the "brownie". I have the following regex to match this:

```
/\b(b|b\.|b_|b\-|8|\|3|ß|Β|β)(r|r\.|r_|r\-|®)(o|o\.|o_|o\-|0|Ο|ο|Φ|¤|°|ø)(w|w\.|w_|w\-|ω|ψ|Ψ)(n|n\.|n_|n\-|η|Ν|Π)\b/i
```

The issue seems to be that `\b` matches the *first* non-word character and because characters like `Π` are non-word characters, that gets matched and not the space afterward. Targeting white space using `\s` doesn't work for consecutive words (it would only match the first "brown" in "the quick brown brown fox").

Any suggestions for how to make this work?

A Regex101 setup: https://regex101.com/r/LKo9Xf/4

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/LKo9Xf/5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the super quick reply. That does seem to do the trick.

Comment: `That does seem to do the trick` No it doesn't https://regex101.com/r/U2nx0q/1 you're drinking the coolaid

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
[b|b\.|b_|b\-|8|\|3|ß|Β|β][[r|r\.|r_|r\-|®][o|o\.|o_|o\-|0|Ο|ο|Φ|¤|°|ø][w|w\.|w_|w\-|ω|ψ|Ψ][n|n\.|n_|n\-|η|Ν|Π](?= )
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xe8pv5/3/)

You need to use character classes for the different leetspeak variations. This will result in single match for each word. Also instead of using `\b` I am using a negative lookahead for a space in the end of each word.

Comment: I just updated my answer due to I misunderstood the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, we could use two lookarounds instead of word boundaries, such as:

> ```
> (?<!\S) and (?!\S) are functionally better whitespace boundary's, and much quicker.
> ```

by [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln), or:

```
(?<=^|\s)(b|b\.|b_|b\-|8|\|3|ß|Β|β)(r|r\.|r_|r\-|®)(o|o\.|o_|o\-|0|Ο|ο|Φ|¤|°|ø)(w|w\.|w_|w\-|ω|ψ|Ψ)(n|n\.|n_|n\-|η|Ν|Π)(?=\s|$)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ljntG0/1)

Comment: `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` are functionally better whitespace boundary's, and much quicker.